# refine the result value from grouped by rows (Can't create VIEW because query contains subquery)

Tags: mysql, group-by, controls

I have the following table:

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  1   |  1        |  50     |
|  2   |  1        |  39     |
|  3   |  1        |  60     |
 ----------------------------
```

What I need is to get the lowest price (39) grouped by product (1) and keep the id (2) of the lowest price.

I have this query

```
SELECT
    id,
    product,
    MIN(price) AS price
FROM
    variant
GROUP BY
    product
```

That results on

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  1   |  1        |  39     |
 ----------------------------
```

But the result I'm looking for is

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  2   |  1        |  39     |
 ----------------------------
```

I was able to get the result using this query

```
select B.id, A.* FROM
(SELECT product,MIN(price) AS minprice 
FROM variant GROUP BY product ) A
JOIN variant B ON A.product = B.product and A.minprice = B.price
```

but I also need to create a view using this query and because there's a subselect inside the from, I cannot create the VIEW.

Is there another way to get the result I was looking for?

I've made a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2ddb2

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view as the subquery,
then create your view joining with the first view instead of a subquery.

```
CREATE VIEW min_variant AS
SELECT product,MIN(price) AS minprice 
FROM variant 
GROUP BY product;

CREATE VIEW min_product AS
SELECT B.id, A.* 
FROM min_variant A
INNER JOIN variant B 
ON A.product = B.product
AND A.minprice = B.price;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea16c6/1